# What happended to beforeUpdate, beforeInsert, beforeSave?

Tags: grails-3.0

In older Grails versions, we had these `beforeUpdate`, `beforeInsert`, `beforeSave` events in domain classes.

I can't find them anymore in Grails 3.x - how can I easily handle these events now?

Update: I just noticed that these events still work but I can't find them in the docs anymore. Are they deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since grails 3.x GORM has it's own docs.

Here is a link to gorm events:

http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Comment: Thanx! I was aware of this but I hit http://doc.gorm.io/callbacks.html through google and didn't notice that this is another gorm!!!